# Search/Replace in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, replace

Been following the threads for sometime as a novice (more of a newbie) but am now starting to do more.

I can read how to open a text file but am having trouble understanding the .replace functionality (I get the syntax just can't get it to work).

**Scenario:**

```
Inputfile name = test_in.txt
```

replace {`inputfile`} with `c:\temp\test1.txt`

I'm using `test.txt` as a template for a scripting tool and need to replace various values within to a new file called `test_2.txt`.

I've got variables defining the input and output files without a problem, I just can't catch the syntax for opening the new file and replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have not given us that much to go on. But a common mistake in using `String.Replace` is that it makes a copy of the source which needs to be saved to another variable or else it will go into the bit bucket. So in your case, something like this should work.

```
Dim Buffer As String 'buffer
Dim inputFile As String = "C:\temp\test.txt" 'template file
Dim outputFile As String = "C:\temp\test_2.txt" 'output file

Using tr As TextReader = File.OpenText(inputFile)
    Buffer = tr.ReadToEnd
End Using
Buffer = Buffer.Replace("templateString", "Hello World")

File.WriteAllText(outputFile, Buffer)
```

Comment: Some great ideas folks -- THANK YOU!

I will try this tonight when I'm at the airport killing time.  Will get back to you both overnight.

Comment: This worked AWESOME!  I was also able to use multiple buffer.replaces without a problem.

I appreciate the help, I hope I can repay it one day..

Comment: +1 He used your solution and you deserve something for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Dim sValuesToReplace() As String = New String() {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"}
Dim sText As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath)

For Each elem As String In sValuesToReplace
    sText = sText.Replace(elem, sNewValue)
Next

IO.File.WriteAllText(sOutputFilePath, sText)
```

It depends if you want to replace all values with only one value, or with different values for each. If you need different values you can use a `Dictionary`:

```
Dim sValuesToReplace As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()

sValuesToReplace.Add("oldValue1", "newValue1")
sValuesToReplace.Add("oldValue2", "newValue2")
'etc
```

And then loop throgh it with:

```
For Each oldElem As String In sValuesToReplace.Keys
    sText = sText.Replace(oldElem, sValuesToReplace(oldElem))
Next
```